# Why is the console text sometimes a different color?

Tags: server, 18.04, colors, console

I have a Ubuntu server (18.04) that rebuilds itself on a schedule. Every once in a while on a fresh install, *all* the console text color will be a different color. Usually it's white on black, but sometimes its blue, green, or red (and maybe others, I can't remember). There doesn't seem to be anything obvious to link it to (bad install, etc).

Is the color there for a reason? What determines what color the text will be?

Comment: To clarify: The color is not just when running ls or another command. *all* of the text is a different color (even MOTD, login banner, prompt, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

When you write something in terminal, it's in white. If you use the `ls` command for showing the content of a directory, each color represents a specific type of file.

**Color of files on 'ls' command:**

- **Executable files**: Green
- **Directory**: Blue
- **Image files(jpg, gif, bmp, png, tif)**: Magenta
- **Symbolic links:** Cyan
- **Pipe**: Yellow
- **Socke**t: Magenta
- **Orphaned symbolic links**: Blinking Bold white with red background
- **Block device driver**: Bold yellow foreground, with black background
- **Missing links along with files they point to**: Blinking Bold white with red background
- **Archives or compressed files(like tar,gz,zip,rpm)**: Red

  [Source](http://pthakkar.com/2013/03/linux-color-files-ls-command/)